# make element cover whole available space when there isn't enough content inside css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an HTML toolbar with some arbitrary height (which I am not explicitly controlling) and main content div (inside a container div) displayed below the toolbar. The quantity of content inside the main content can vary.

I want if the content's available isn't enough to cover the whole screen then the main content div should cover remaining height available on screen below toolbar. If the content is more than the screen size then it should display a proper vertical scrollbar to display complete content.

my structure is like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <toolbar></toolbar>
        <container>
            <main div>...</main div>
        </container>
    </body>
</html>
```

currently my css for main body and html looks like:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container{
    height: 100%
    width:100%
}
#main-div{
    // how to make it full screen when there isn't enough content
}
```

Comment: sorry for that.

Comment: No problem :) ... sometimes another solution fits better so don't feel you have to change, was just asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox, where you make the `body` a flex container with column direction, give the `container` `flex: 1` to fill the remaining height and make that one also a flex container, with row direction, and finally give the `main` `flex: 1` to fill the remain horizontally.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
main {
 flex: 1;
 background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  toolbar
</div>
<div class="container">
  <main>main</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` with column direction to achieve the desired result

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
#main-div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <toolbar>
          Content of toolbar with unknow height and you have no control of it
        </toolbar>
        <main id="main-div">
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
          Some content <br />
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```